# Google maps in android gray grid

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use mapviews in an app, so I followed the steps one by one. But I got just a gray grid. I generated the API key four times, but get the same result every time.

could you please help me?

These are the errors I got:

```
failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
couldn't get connection factory client
```

my manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.test.g_maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
         <uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
         <uses-permission     android:name="com.me.test.g_maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
         <uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <permission
        android:name="com.me.test.g_maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
            android:name="com.me.test.g_maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCEgLQ7HgXiKTP8grZRmpIPAeWoSfAjrBM"/>

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        </application>

        </manifest>
```

my activity

```
    package com.me.test.g_maps;

    import android.os.Bundle;

   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    }
```

my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="AIzaSyCEgLQ7HgXiKTP8grZRmpIPAeWoSfAjrBM"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you able to put your manifest here?

Comment: you can see the manifest file now with the question

Comment: please post you java class and activity layout xml as well.

Answer (score 1):

As it looks you have few problems (in case your targeting Google Map API V2 technology)

**1.** First of all remove this permission:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

It's a part of Google Maps API V1 and is not needed in Google Maps API V2.

**2.** Google Maps API V2 needs OpenGL-v2 support, and therefor you have to add the following to your manifest file:

```
<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>
```

**3.** Check that you are turning on the right API in the Google API Console:
[image]

**4.** Try to regenerate the key again, by deleting the `debug.keystore`, compiling a project and that will result in a new `SHA1` signature.

**5.**  If you run your application in the emulator, check this blog post I wrote on how to enable Google Map API V2 in the emulator:

[Google Map API V2 in the Emulator](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527)

Comment: i tried everything but still not working , thanks anyway, may be it's the emulator!!

Comment: Not maybe, it's the emulator but you can adjust it to run Google Maps API V2 in it, check this blog post I wrote: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google api V1, you have to [create a debug key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey?hl=es#getdebugfingerprint) to load correctly the map when you are debugging the app without signing it.
Else, you have to take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key). New configuration on manifest is needed to use google maps api V2.

Comment: i get sha1 certificate when i enter it they told me it's not a valid one

Comment: With `keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name.keystore` you will get the Certificate fingerprints. Then in the [Google Apis panel](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) you have to add the fingerprint followed by a semicolon and your package name: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;com.me.test.g_maps

Answer (score 0):

Replace `com.google.android.maps.MapView` with `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. You are still using parts of Maps API V1. And it's better (easier) to use SupportMapFragment instead of MapView.

And don't use `MapActivity` either.